# confilict between two plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have two plugins (local code - not downloads) that import data from XML files.

The first plugin works fine. I then duplicated the plugin to work on a completely separate XML file. I renamed the directory/plugin-name/plugin-code.

When I activate the second plugin two weird things happen. The original plugin tries to activate the import code for the second plugin - how it does that I have no idea. Secondly, the second plugin gives a 500 error after it completes.

I deactivated the first plugin and tried the second plugin and it works fine. After re-activating the first plugin it fails.

Is there something in wordpress that causes this sort of conflict?

I know this question is not specifically code based but I guess the answer is.
I am just not smart enough to know how wordpress would create this conflict.

Comment: It is likely the first plugin needs to be destroyed in jQuery when calling second plugin or you need to handle the request and direct to proper plugin.  Typically plugins are designed for multi-use. Try and do research on plugin and give us some information regarding what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't use same plugin copy. Because of how programming languages work, loading the same plugin twice will result in both versions trying to define the same functions and classes. PHP won't stand for that, and will die with a fatal error.

If you want to use the plugin before that you have rename classes and function of that plugin file. A main reason for check existence of function.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_awesome_function' ) ) {
/**
 * My Awesome function is awesome
 *
 * @param array $args
 * @return array
 */
function my_awesome_function( $args ) {
  //function stuff
  return array();
  }
}
```

In above code this will check if function not exist then declare it.

Comment: Thanks to Guillermo Carone and Vasim Vanzara. You were both correct in your description. I checked this reply as it was the closest to the problem.

Comment: @LisaWhiteBarrett-Handley Thank you for appreciation

Answer (score 1):

A plugin is basically a series of functions. By duplicating your plugin you are duplicating your functions which is causing the conflict. If you want to duplicate your plugin you won’t just need to duplicate and rename the folder but you’ll also need to rename your functions in the second plugin, otherwise you’ll be redeclaring already declared functions.